# Getting different results between PHP SDK and Graph API explorer

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm facing the following problem:

When I'm trying to read all the comments from a posto of me on facebook via the Facebook php sdk ( Graph API) i can't get all of them, while when I am using the Facebook Graph API explorer, they are all appearing.

My App's permissions are the same with Graph API explorer's permissions.

Any ideas?
Thanks..

Comment: Graph API explorer also allows you to choose the app you are running under (top right drop down).  What happens if you use explorer running as your app?

Comment: I get the expected results. All of the comments are appearing normally.

Comment: But while via my app I see all of the likes, the comments appear to be 0, and they are more than 10 for a specific post. In Graph API Explorer all of them are apperaing normally.

Comment: Use Firefox or Chrome developer tools network tab to examine the request that is being sent to Facebook in each case and compare them.  I bet you are doing something different in your app vs. what you are doing in Graph explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you authenticating as a user in your PHP app? In the Graph API explorer, by default you have a user access token. If your app is just using the app id & secret, you will not see any post marked with a privacy less than "everyone."

You can test this in the explorer by [getting an app access_token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/) and pasting this into the access token box in the graph explorer.

Answer (score 1):

in the Graph API Explorer, try to change Application (by default is Graph API Explorer) with your App.

if still can't get all of the comments, just delete you App, and recreate.